# "Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2.." However, it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Really weird error I've never gotten before, hoping someone else has seen this.

I'm trying to `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset` and I'm getting

> Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources.  Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.

I have ran `bundle install` and I see nokogiri installed:

```
cli:~/projects/interviews/my_folder/name_generator$ bundle install
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 1.0.1
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.2 <------------ Here?!
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.1.6
Using rack 2.0.5
Using rack-test 1.0.0
Using actionpack 5.1.6
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.6
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.1.6
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 5.1.6
Using activemodel 5.1.6
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.6
Using activerecord-import 0.23.0
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using byebug 10.0.2
Using xpath 3.0.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using ffi 1.9.23
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.1.6
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using pg 1.0.0
Using pry 0.11.3
Using puma 3.11.4
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.1.6
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 3.12.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
Using turbolinks 5.1.1
Using uglifier 4.1.10
Using web-console 3.6.2
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 73 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
clil:~/projects/interviews/John_Gray/name_generator$ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
cli:~/projects/interviews/John_Gray/name_generator$
```

Comment: Can you remove Gemfile.lock and try?

Comment: Try to run `bundle doctor` or `bundle show` and post any unusual results. Just a guess.

Comment: Try uninstalling it and installing it again. Sometimes it's "installed" but the dependencies are broken so it can't load. Also try a minimal script like `require 'nokogiri'` to see if that works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I removed the Gemfile.lock  - to no avail.  I ran bundle doctor and received "The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied.
No issues found with the installed bundle." I tried 'require nokogiri' in IRB and it returns true.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Timmy given your output you ran `bundle install` in a different folder than where you are running the rake task from e.g. *"my_folder/name_generator$ bundle install"* and *"John_Gray/name_generator$ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset"* This will cause an issue and you should run the install from the root where you intend to run the rake task from

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, Thanks, that's a good catch.  That log is from my flurry of trying to figure out what is going on.  
Running everything from the /John_Gray/name_generator produces the same "Could not find nokogiri..." error.  
On top of that I'm running this in a Ruby 2.5.1 with Rails 5.1.6 environment via RVM.  When I try to run anything in this environment (even create a blank scaffold) any rake tasks return the "Could not find nokogiri..." error.  If I revert to Ruby 2.4.2 with Rails 4.x or 5.0.x the error does not come up and everything is successful.  So I figure it may be RVM?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says "nokkogiri" but the gem's name is "nokogiri." (Only one 'k').

Comment: I like the way you look so closely at things :)

Comment: The actual terminal error shows the correct spelling so this appears to just be a transposition typo and I am not sure that this qualifies as an "answer"

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

also see these installation options 
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  I tried this method and get the same error.  It looks like it is installed, but does not run.  I also am able to `require 'nokogiri'` in an IRB console and it works.

Comment: Can you also try un/re install bundler,

Also what version of Ruby are you using, if you have version manager like RVM and Rbenv then try to remove that Ruby verision and reinstall it as well.